# How to make a pdf file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

How can I make a PDF file in PHP. What I want to make is a student list. So I want to query the database, get the information and give it to the user as a PDF when he clicks generate student list.

Answer (score 12):

You have two good options first is the standard php library for manipulating pdf's: https://www.php.net/pdf

Or you can use http://www.fpdf.org/. I would recommend the second.

Other options include:
[www.pdflib.com](http://www.pdflib.com)

Comment: Another recommendation for fpdf. Had performed well for us, even under heavy loads.

Answer (score 1):

PEAR has the [PEAR::File_PDF](http://pear.php.net/package/File_PDF) package.

Answer (score 1):

There are are already many libraries available with PHP bindings. One that comes to mind is PDFLib (www.pdflib.com). If I am not mistaken there should even be a lite version that you can use for free. But just check it out.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I use the [ezPDF](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/) class.  Lightweight, simple, easy to use, and handles most cases.

Answer (score 0):

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) is a classical in the field. It seems it has limitations when handling Unicode (eg. Asian char sets), so there are libraries extending it ([UFPDF](http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf), [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf)...).